# Conditionally display line in freemarker template

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

I'm creating a PDF from a sorted array of JSON objects, sorted by task, where each object, e.g. `JSON.arr[0] == i`, contains memo, rate, amount and taskText.

I want to display the task on its own line only if the current task is the first task, or different from the previous task.  Nothing is being displayed for taskText.

```
<#if JSON?has_content>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">MEMO</th>
    <th>RATE</th>
    <th>AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
  <#list JSON.arr as i>
    <#if i?first>
      <#assign task = i.taskText>
      <tr><td>${i.taskText}</td></tr>
    </#if>
    <#if i.taskText != task>
      <#assign task = i.taskText>
      <tr><td>${i.taskText}</td></tr>
    </#if>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">${i.memo}</td>
      <td>$${i.rate}</td>
      <td>$${i.amount}</td>
    </tr>
  </#list>
</table>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `?is_first` instead of `?first`. It is used to check whether the current item is the first one in the current list.

For the other requirement, I would suggest to assign an initial value to `task` **before** the loop. It may well be that task is never set to anything other than `null` and comparison therefore fails.

Comment: Assigning the initial value before the loop was not necessary.  `?is_first` solved the problem.